# Command line args not passed on to Python script

Tags: python, cmd

Mine is the same basic question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530303/python-script-args-not-transferred-to-script), but the answers there don't help me.

Given this Python script, `argv.py`:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print sys.argv
```

If I execute it with `python argv.py foo` it displays `['argv.py', 'foo']`.

If I execute it with `argv.py foo` it displays `['M:\\Projects\\SomaLogic\\CmdLine\\argv.py']`. What I expected here was `['foo']`.

The result of `assoc .py` is `.py=Python.File`.

The result of `ftype Python.File` is `Python.File="C:\Python27.10\python.exe" "%1" %*`.

EDIT: added expectation for the failing case.

Comment: It's never going to be ['foo'] because the 0th arg is always supposed to be the script. Not entirely clear where the rest of your args are disappearing to, though.

Comment: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/12/14/problem-passing-arguments-to-python-scripts-on-windows   seems to have better luck by changing the registry

Comment: Is `%*` the right flag? I seem to remember that being something different but it's been a while since I've been on Windows. Plus you can use `py argv.py foo` so it's not a load of extra characters that you have to type...

Comment: @WayneWerner, that's how it's [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#id3)

Comment: Good enough for me :)

Comment: @pvg, thanks. The registry change does fix the problem. I don't get why the assoc+ftype configuration doesn't yield the same thing. Now I have to untangle which of my Pythons, if any, are from ActiveState; I didn't think I'd installed that on my machine. (The customer, however, does use ActiveState.)

Comment: You might consider bundling your entire environment with something like py2exe  if your goal is actual distribution to random machines. It's a whole other can of worms but at least you'll only have to do it locally once.