# sys.argv works when running 'python file.py' but not on just 'file'

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, sys

Title says it all, I've written a script called file.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

When running it as `python test.py arguments` it works, returning successfuly, but when running it as `test arguments` using the python that's linked on %path%, it doesn't show the arguments, just the file path as argument 0. No problems with the version of python, both are the same version.

What's going on here? Python 3.4.3 on Win7 x64

EDIT: Solved using [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/12/14/problem-passing-arguments-to-python-scripts-on-windows)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43079413/744178

Comment: @jwodder Thanks, solved it.

Comment: Please consider adding your own answer (as an answer, clicking the "Post Your Answer" button) describing the solution you used. The linked question is also unanswered, so right now they can't be linked as duplicates until one or the other has been solved. (Note that link-only answers, like link-only questions, aren't acceptable here -- we want to have a knowledgebase that's durable even if external links break).

Comment: Used a link found in one of the comments, x-posted the link in main post.